How to get the exact radius of an Arc in Paper.js?
I have an arc already created. I want to get the radius of that arc. I tried using the getCurvatureAtTime() method. But it's not giving correct result. Is there any way I can find the exact radius of that curve?
I have tried using this paper sketch. It should give a result of 1 at each location but I'm getting different values at different curve locations.
var from = new Point(1, 0);
var through = new Point(0, 1);
var to = new Point(-1, 0);
var arcPath = new Path.Arc(from, through, to);
arcPath.fillColor = 'red'

console.log("0: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[0].getCurvatureAtTime(0))
console.log("0.25: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[0].getCurvatureAtTime(0.25))
console.log("0.5: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[0].getCurvatureAtTime(0.5))
console.log("0.75: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[0].getCurvatureAtTime(0.75))
console.log("1: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[0].getCurvatureAtTime(1))

console.log("0: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[1].getCurvatureAtTime(0))
console.log("0.25: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[1].getCurvatureAtTime(0.25))
console.log("0.5: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[1].getCurvatureAtTime(0.5))
console.log("0.75: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[1].getCurvatureAtTime(0.75))
console.log("1: \t", 1/arcPath.curves[1].getCurvatureAtTime(1))

